# Localized version offers upgrade to en-us version

Tags: localization, upgrade

My Dutch 4.2.5 version offers to update to `WordPress 4.3.1–en_US` when I visit the dashboard.

I'm surprised that it does not offer an upgrade to something like `WordPress 4.3.1–nl_NL`

Will this work properly?

I do not remember how this went with earlier versions (i.e. what those offered).

[Edited to add]

Five minutes after posting this question a mail comes in which translates to: *Your site has been automatically updated to WordPress 4.2.5*. It is correct that automatic updates are on for this specific site.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering my own question)

It is now 1 week after posting my question. I just revisited the dashboard.
There are now two updates available: `WordPress 4.3.1–nl_NL` and `WordPress 4.3.1–en_US`.

So it looks as if the localized update takes some more time to prepare.

I will not click anything right now, assuming that the update will go automatically.

To be continued...

Added: Yes, the automatic update to the Dutch version came through...